# Entity Framework 6 foreign key and target column of different types

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

recently a sql server GIS database was updated which changed several data types.

I now have table named Trail with a Column named Status of type Numeric(40,0)   this is to be a foreign key to Table named Trail_Status with column named Status_Key (int)

here was my attempt.

```
 public class TrailConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<TrailModel>
    {
        public TrailConfiguration()
        {
            this.ToTable("PA_TRAILS", "dbo");

            this.Property(p => p.StatusKey)
                .HasColumnName("STATUS")
                .HasColumnType("numeric")
                .IsRequired();

              this.HasRequired(p => p.Status)
                .WithMany()
                .HasForeignKey(k => k.StatusKey);
      }
  }
```

---

```
public class TrailModel 
{
    [Column(TypeName = "numeric")]
    public int StatusKey { get; set; }

     public virtual TrailStatusModel Status { get; set; }
 }
```

---

```
 public TrailStatusConfiguration()
    {
        this.ToTable("trail_status", "dbo");

        this.HasKey(k => k.StatusKey);

        this.Property(p => p.StatusKey)
            .HasColumnName("status_key")
            .HasColumnType("int")
            .IsRequired();

        this.Property(p => p.Name)
            .HasColumnName("name")
            .HasColumnType("nvarchar")
            .IsRequired();
    }
```

---

```
public class TrailStatusModel
    {
        public int StatusKey { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

I receive the following error.

> TrailStatusModel_TrailModel: : The types of all properties in the
>   Dependent Role of a referential constraint must be the same as the
>   corresponding property types in the Principal Role. The type of
>   property 'STATUS' on entity 'TrailModel' does not match the type of
>   property 'status_key' on entity 'TrailStatusModel' in the referential
>   constraint 'TrailModel_Status'.

Comment: The types need to match, otherwise you are looking at more complex options like an extraneous mapping table, creating a view or using JOINs. Are you not in control of either table? The vendor provided a database without referential integrity?

Comment: yeah I thought that might be the case, thanks.